# How does the windows' command "Send to" works?

Tags: windows, command

(Command "Send to" in right-click on a file)

When I find in registry the content of "Send to" command in Windows, I found this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cwz2a.png

So exactly what does the string of number `{7BA4C740-9E81-11CF-99D3-00AA004AE837}` means, how does the command "Send to" works and how can I create a similar Service (by code)?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have some code trying to do it yourself? In what programming language you want to do this?

Comment: Do you want to add an item in the sendto menu?

Comment: @Meryovi: C#. I had tried more times by myself, but I can't. Because I don't understand exactly what services in windows are, how it works. I want to learn how to create a service for my software like KAV, bonjour services... (3th party service)


\n foxidrive: No. It's simply editing "Send to" folder, I know that. I mean deeper